# Meaning of the Shadow Broker recordings?

Tags: mass-effect-2

At the end of the [Lair of the Shadow Broker](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Lair_of_the_Shadow_Broker) DLC (which was awesome!), you are shown various security camera recordings. They are short, silent, and provide little context.

I couldn't recognize any of the characters or events. Do any of these show past events we are supposed to remember, or events from any other media like the novels? Or do they all foreshadow Mass Effect 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The videos themselves are pretty meaningless - they're just supposed to be a neat, almost easter-egg snippets of video footage that the Shadow Broker was ostensibly observing / had recorded.

You may not have recognized any of the characters, but the folks over at the [Mass Effect wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Video_Archive) have gotten a pretty comprehensive list.

Also, note that not all the videos are available at once -- I have a feeling you'd remember [Khalisah al-Jilani](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Khalisah_al-Jilani), especially when she's getting punched and kicked (and this time, not by you!)

Comment: Personally, I'm hoping she'll make a return in ME3 so I can go for the hat-trick :)

Answer (score -1):

These are mostly characters we all no, Captain Anderson, Samara, Aria etc.
Its footage of past events, Its basically just there for you to see what the Shadow Broker has been seeing and spying on.. I think its pretty cool.